# Nonnegativity of sparse polynomial with just one negative coefficient

Tags: inequality, polynomials, semialgebraic-geometry

Consider the polynomial

$$
P(x,y)=15 \times 10^{15} (x^4+y^4)+2 \times 9999^2 \times 10^{12} xy(x+y-3)+20001 \times 9999^4
$$

One can show that $P(x,y)\geq 0$ when $x,y\geq 0$ (proof is below). Since $P$ has only one negative coefficient, one would expect that there is a simple proof of this nonnegativity property of $P$.

However, so far I only found the ugly proof at the end of this question which uses integers with more than $20$ digits.

**My question:** Is there a simpler method ?

**My thoughts:** The middle part of $P$ resembles the Motzkin polynomial ; if we put $m(x,y)=xy(x+y-3)+1$ we have $m(x,y)\geq 0$ by AM-GM. This suggest rewriting $P$ as $P(x,y)=15 \times 10^{15}(x^4+y^4)+2 \times 9999^2 \times 10^{12}m(x,y)-3\times 9999^2 \times 10^8$, but unfortunately we still have a negative coefficient.

Here is my painstaking proof. Let $r=1-\frac{1}{10^4}$ (note that $P(r,r)=0$) and $l=r+\frac{3332}{6669}(r-x)$.

When $x\leq 4$, we have $P(x,y)\geq 0$ because

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
P(x,y)= & \bigg(c_1+c_2(4-x)+c_3(4-x)^2+\big(c_4+c_5(4-x)\big)y\bigg)(x-r)^2 \\ 
& + (c_6+c_7l^2)(y-l)^2+c_8(y^2-l^2)^2
\end{array}
$$

where

$$
\begin{array}{c}
c_1=\frac{1632689280798968825215\times 10^7}{32043471291},c_2=\frac{ 30294845044444411219\times 10^{12}}{608825954529}, \\
c_3=\frac{2680495655043655\times 10^{15}}{219786169584969},c_4=\frac{897083745816842\times 10^{12}}{5203640637},c_5=\frac{73985220736\times 10^{16}}{98869172103},\\
c_6= 199960002\times 10^{12}, c_7=3\times 10^{16}, c_8=15\times 10^{15}
\end{array}
$$

So we may assume WLOG that $x\gt 4$. By symmetry, we may also assume $y\gt 4$. Then $x+y-3\geq 5$, the middle part of $P$ is positive and we are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x + y \ge 3$, clearly $P(x, y) \ge 0$.

If $x + y < 3$, using
$x^4 + y^4 \ge (x + y)^4/8$ (power mean inequality) and $xy \le \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}$, it suffices to prove that
$$15 \times 10^{15} \cdot \frac{(x+y)^4}{8}
+ 2 \times 9999^2 \times 10^{12} \cdot \frac{(x+y)^2}{4} \cdot (x + y - 3) + 20001 \times 9999^4 \ge 0.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $u\ge 0$,
$$15 \times 10^{15} \cdot \frac{u^4}{8}
+ 2 \times 9999^2 \times 10^{12} \cdot \frac{u^2}{4} \cdot (u - 3) + 20001 \times 9999^4 \ge 0$$
or (multiplying both sides by $16/9999^4$)
$$3\left(\frac{10^4u}{9999}\right)^4
+ 8\times 9999\times  \left(\frac{10^4u}{9999}\right)^3
- 24 \times 10^4  \left(\frac{10^4u}{9999}\right)^2 + 16\times 20001 \ge 0.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $v \ge 0$,
$$3v^4 + 8\times 9999 v^3 - 24 \times 10^4v^2 + 16 \times 20001 \ge 0$$
or (letting $a = 9999$)
$$3v^4 + 8av^3 - 24(1 + a)v^2 + 16(2a + 3) \ge 0$$
or
$$(8v^3 - 24v^2 + 32)a + 3v^4 - 24v^2 + 48 \ge 0$$
or
$$8(v+1)(v-2)^2 a + 3(v^2 - 4)^2 \ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.

Comment: Nice, this is already better than what I did. I'll wait a little bit before accepting this answer in case a better one comes up

Comment: +1 with the observation that this works so nicely because the minimum is in fact attained at a point where $\,x=y\,$, specifically $\,x=y= (a-1)/a\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. Yes, this makes it done by hand. I edited.